# How to fit a Dictionary into a CSV file with all the values in the keys in a different column within the same row in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, dictionary, export-to-csv

I have a Dictionary and I wish to save it into a csv file. However, using the code below, the value (ei. All the data in the key are put in one cell all together). However, I required for each value to be in a different column within the same row of the key it belongs to.

```
csvPatientListFinal = csv.writer(open('PatientListFinal.csv','wb'))
    for key, value in PatientList.items():
        csvPatientListFinal.writerow([key, value])
```

I have tried however I have been unsuccessful in my efforts.

Thank you

Update 1:

Sorry about the typo, however the code worked (it was written in the script without typos), but it was not the desired output. The Dictionary created by my script has 14 keys, and 721 items inside each key. They are a database of case subjects. An example of the Dictionary is the following: I use the  "|" so represent the lines between each cell, my mistake. The data in the dictionary look like this:

```
PatientList = {'code' : ['1','2','3','4','5',6], 'name' : ['aho','awd','faw','fas','gas','gdas','fasw'] , 'surnames' : ['awds','fhtt','hfr','hyk','uyr','rtyd'], 'ID' : ['123','345','654','234','645','354'], 'description' : ['a long text','a long text','a long text','a long text','a long text','a long text'] }.
```

The csv table format should be ("|" is the space between each cell in a row)

> (headers)A|B|C
>
> (row 1)1|A|caro
>
> (row 2)2|B|al

But the input that I had was

> (headers in one cell) A,B,C
>
> (row 1 in one cell) 1 A caro
>
> (row 2 in one cell) 2 B al

All under the same column, that correspond to the key they belong. This is an image representation of the desired output:

[image]

I am now trying the following code:

```
csvPatientListFinal = csv.writer(open('PatientListFinal.csv','wb'))
    for header in PatienList.keys():
        csvPatientListFinal.writerow(izip[header, value for value in PatientList[header]])
```

However, it indicates, an Error of Invalid syntax in the area of "value for value". I am trying to figure out why.

Is there a better way to achieve my desired output? Is there something wrong with the code (apart from the syntax error which I currently can't guess why it is there)?

Thank you for the help

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this. Iterate over the length of the value lists (assuming they're all the same length as the one in `code`) with nested iteration over the keys.

```
with open('PatientListFinal.csv', 'w') as fp:
    csvPatientListFinal = csv.writer(fp)
    csvPatientListFinal.writerow(PatientList.keys())
    for i in range(len(PatientList['code'])):
        csvPatientListFinal.writerow([j[i] for j in PatientList.values()])
```

You might want to consider using an `OrderedDict` if order is important to you. There's currently no guarantee that the columns will be stored in the same order as they was entered.

Comment: Thanks Ste, that was a typo while I was writing the question, however the code does not contain that type. Thank you for pointing it out. I have updated my progress on my own question, do you mind looking at it? And see if you can help me out?

Comment: I use the  "|" so represent the lines between each cell, my mistake. PatientList = {'code' : ['1','2','3','4','5',6], 'name' : ['aho','awd','faw','fas','gas','gdas','fasw'] , 'surnames' : ['awds','fhtt','hfr','hyk','uyr','rtyd'], 'ID' : ['123','345','654','234','645','354'], 'description' : ['a long text','a long text','a long text','a long text','a long text','a long text'] }

Comment: Apologies, I misunderstood. This one should fix it for you now!